# "No module named _cairo" using Jython 2.7

Tags: java, python, jython, cairo

I am trying to use python's charting library from my java project using jython. In my script I use module cairo.

```
pythonInterpreter.exec("import sys");
pythonInterpreter.exec("import cairo");
```

Exception throws on the second line, because  `cairo's` **init**.py contains string:

```
from _cairo import *
```

The exception I get is:

```
Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _cairo import *
ImportError: No module named _cairo
```

Also, I can use my script from console, so I doubt that it has an error in it. I suppose something is wrong with the way I'm importing cairo in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it now. Jython can't execute 'native' libraries, such as cairo (I'm, sure it's native, because _cairo is a .so file, which means it's a C lib)